# how to make different sum over the same line in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with, some numeric columns. 
I would like to make several aggregationg operations on these columns creating a new column for each function, some of which may also be user defined.

The easy solution would be using dataframe and withColumn. For istance, if I wanted to calculate the mean (by hand) and the function my_function on fields field_1 and field_2 I would do:

```
df=df.withColumn("mean",(df["field_1"]+df["field_2])/2)
df=df.withColumn("foo", my_function(df["field_1"],df["field_2]))
```

My doubt is about efficiency. Each of the 2 above functions scans the whole database while a smarter approach would calculate both results using one single scan.

Any hint on how to do that?

Thanks

Mauro

Comment: if you want to do both computations in one setting, you can use `df.select("*", ((df["field_1"]+df["field_2])/2).alias("mean"), my_function(df["field_1"],df["field_2]).alias("foo"))` but it won't be more efficient. All the compuations will be done when you do an operation on the df (show, collect, write...) so it doesn't matter if you implement them sequentially or in one setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You're trying to solve problem which doesn't exist

SQL transformations are lazy and declarative. Series of operations is converted into logical execution plan, and then into physical execution plan. At the first stage Spark optimizer has freedom to reorder, combine or even remove any part of the plan. You have to however, distinguish between two cases:

- Python `udf`.
- SQL expression.

The first requires separate conversion to Python RDD. It cannot be combined with native processing. The second one is processed natively using generated code.

Once you request the results physical plan is converted into stages and executed.